# Largest triangle to fit in a circle will be isosceles triangle?

Tags: geometry

Largest triangle to fit in a circle will be isosceles triangle?
Or some other type?

Comment: More specifically, equilateral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you say is true, but you can say more than that.

Given a particular chord of a circle, you can maximize the area of the triangle by having the third vertex as far away as possible (area is half base times perpendicular height), which means that it will be on the perpendicular bisector of the chord where it crosses the circle, the other side of the circle's centre.  So with this chord as an edge, the area will be maximised if the other two edges are equal, i.e. if the triangle is isosceles.

But the same thing is true of the other two edges, and that implies ... (*I will leave you to work this out*)

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but your reasoning is not enough to conclude that the equilateral triangle is the best. All you can conclude is that for any non-equilateral triangle, there is a better one. You need either compactness of the solution space or a more careful smoothing argument.